# Left aligning absolutely positioned div while maintaining fluidity

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="left">
        <div id="leftContainer"><span>bla</span><span>bla</span><span>bla</span><span>bla</span></div>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        <div class="item"><span>item text 1</span></div>
        <div class="item"><span>item text 2</span></div>
        <div class="item"><span>item text 3</span></div>
        <div class="item"><span>item text 4</span></div>
        <div class="item"><span>item text 5</span></div>
        <div class="item"><span>item text 6</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With the corresponding styles:

```
#left, #right {
    display: inline-block;
}
.item {
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0px 5px;
}
#right {
    position: absolute;
    /*right:0px;*/ /*this little thing causes my problems*/
    text-align:right;
    border-color: red;
}
```

I need the `right` `div` to be right aligned. For that I set `right:0px;` but then the `right` element overlap the `left` `div`. If `right:0px;` is not set, then the `item` elements will break on a new line (which is part of my requirements) but the `right` element will be, obviously, left aligned. See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j0pfkuot/), comment/uncomment `right:0px;` and play with the width of the result panel.

Is the a way of right aligning the `right` `div` without overlapping? Floating is currently not a solution.

Comment: Is it a requirement that `#left` and `#right` still behave as 2 columns when `#outer` gets narrower? Or should be they be stacked vertically in that case, and in which order?

Comment: @NicolasLeThierryd'Ennequin, they can be stacked, with `left` being on top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear on how the right div is supposed to behave after the 'collision' point but flexbox does allow for the alignment you wanted without the overlap that seems to be problematical for you.

```
#outer {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```css
#outer {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#left div span {
  margin: 0px 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 5px;
}
#right {
  text-align: right;
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="left">
    <div id="leftContainer">
      <span>bla</span>
      <span>bla</span>
      <span>bla</span>
      <span>bla</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <div class="item"><span>item text 1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item"><span>item text 2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item"><span>item text 3</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item"><span>item text 4</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item"><span>item text 5</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item"><span>item text 6</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/j0pfkuot/7/)

Comment: This is the closest solution to what I need. There is one small issue, though: the width of the `left` `div` changes with that of the `outer` `div` -- this is only visible after the "collision".

Comment: It works, thank you. Flex was what I was thinking. I'm going to accept this as an answer as it's the most elegant solution provided. One question though: is there a way of maintaining the hight of the `left` container and maybe hiding the overflowing content of `right`?

Comment: I do not think so, I'd have to do some more research but hiding the overflow is not really what flexbox is about,

Comment: The `item` elements do not break on IE 10. Do you have a solution/workaround?

Comment: I do not but you can read more about flexbox [**Here**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 1):

As i understand you need something like following.

Use `display:table-cell` will solve your issue:

```
#left, #right {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Check [Fiddle Here.](http://jsfiddle.net/j0pfkuot/5/)

Give `width: 100%;` to `.right` wills stick right div to right align.

Check Updated  [Fiddle Here.](http://jsfiddle.net/j0pfkuot/8/)

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve the "right align the `right` `div`" part of my problem.

Comment: No... I need the entire `right` `div` to be right aligned. Please see the original fiddle and just uncomment `right:0px;`.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Unfortunately `display: table-cell;` does not really go with the overall "structure" of the project design. This, however, does not mean that your solution does not cover everything I asked for. Your solution is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Use the flexbox model `display: flex` for your `#right` element.

```
#outer {
  overflow: hidden;
}  

#left {
  float: left;
  min-width: 66%;
  background-color: #69f;
}

#right {
  min-width: 34%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

See example here: http://jsbin.com/qalilu/3/edit. I've added a `min-width` constraint, which may be useful.

See browser support: http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox
And a guide: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/